# How to get full absolute url for post attachment?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images, open-graph

I'm trying to manually fill the Open Graph tags and I'm having some troubles in setting the content for the `og:image` tag.

In a single post page, I set it this way:

```
<?php
$thumbnailSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
$image        = esc_attr($thumbnailSrc[0]);
?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image ?>">
```

The result is this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg">
```

On the Open Graph debugger I then get this error:

```
Object at URL 'http://website.com' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.
```

How can I get the attachment so that the url is: http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg ?

Answer (score 1):

`esc_attr()` might not be necessary on the `url` retrieved by `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.

I have referred to a [code example from the WordPress Codex page on wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/#comment-328) and adapted the following code that works for me.

```
global $post;
$thumbnailSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
if ( $thumbnailSrc ) :
  echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$thumbnailSrc[0].'">';
endif;
```

Edit: Since you are using the $post object outside of the WordPress loop you will need to declare `global $post;` before you use `$post->ID`. I have added it to the code sample above.

Comment: I've actually tried that. It's always echoing only `/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg`

Comment: Hmmm, I have tested the code and I get an absolute url. I tested inside the WordPress loop but I see you would be placing your code outside of the loop in the `<head>`. You might need to make the $post object global before you use `$post->ID`. I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I tried with this, but nothing changed. I imagine I would have gotten an error if the `$post` variable wasn't accessible. My code is working, it retrieves the image, it just doesn't have the full path

Answer (score 1):

You could use [has_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) and [get_the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) to get an absolute url for the posts feature image.

According to the Codex `has_post_thumbnail()` will check if the post has an image attached and `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` will return the post thumbnail URL.

I have tested the code below:

```
global $post;
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
  echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID).'">';
}
```

As mentioned in a previous comment, you are using the $post object before the WordPress loop starts and will need to declare `global $post;` before you can use `$post->ID`.

Comment: I just tried this and nothing. At this point, it must be something in the theme, but I don't know where to look. I'm using the Roots Sage theme, by the way

Answer (score 1):

To access the current post object outside **The Loop**, you need to declare the `$post` variable globally.

```
<?php global $post; ?>
<meta property="og:image" 
    content="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(($post->ID)); ?>">
```